# Make the column with the line numbers wider

Tags: themes

How can I make the column with the line numbers wider?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the appearance of `linum-mode` by setting values for `linum-format`.

Add something like this to your `.emacs` file :- `(setq linum-format "%3s")` [to have your `linum-mode` numbers be at least 3 characters wide].

Comment: that worked but since the text is right-justified i still can't see all the numbers.. that is, there's more space to the left of the numbers. any ideas? & thanks!

Comment: ahHA! i just added a space to the format: `(setq linum-format "%3s ")`